# Passing parameters to Liferay's services search function

Tags: elasticsearch, liferay, liferay-7

I need to use Liferay's index for searching users that match a determined string, and this is possible by using `UserLocalServiceImpl#search(long companyId, String keywords, int status, LinkedHashMap<String,Object> params, int start, int end, com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.Sort sort)`.

Furthermore I'd like to be able to filter the users by `UserGroup`.

I would expect that I could pass the `userGroupId` to this function into `params`, but it doesn't look like I can find any documentation about what `params` should be.

By taking a look at the [source code](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/bfb0550e8b57dc3424ef19051084ba2c9e4c7c7e/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/service/impl/UserLocalServiceImpl.java#L3224) it looks like it is being added to a `SearchContext` used to produce the query, but I'm not being able to follow down the code to the point where is then used.

Do anyone know anything about what can I put into `params` for this purpose?

I'm on a Liferay CE version 7.0

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look add [UserIndexer.java](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/7.0.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portlet/usersadmin/util/UserIndexer.java) in method addContextQueryParams.
It looks like the param key should be `usersGroups` an it should hava a Long[] value. There are some other keys handled here, so you could gain some information how params are processed here (debugger?).

Comment: Yes, this actually made sense to me, but by enabling the logs for indexers and so taking a look at the queries that were being made to elasticsearch it turned out that `usersGroups` is not a list of IDs of `UserGroup`s, but the `Group` IDs for the `User`s to be filtered